# Django: Possible to load fixtures with date fields based on the current date?

Tags: django

I want to load fixtures into django. The data has some `date` fields - is it possible to create these data so they will always be e.g. yesterday or tomorrow? I want to make sure certain data is always fresh, but also so I can easily test edge cases (e.g. whether an object is enabled if the publishing date is today, etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixtures just load text data files (in JSON/XML/YAML) so, there's no real way to insert dynamically generated data by just loading a fixture.  On the other hand, you can get around this using other methods.

One option is the package [django-fixture-generator](http://github.com/alex/django-fixture-generator) where you can write python/django code to create data and it will be inserted before your tests are called.

Another option is a previous SO question: [How to load sql fixture in Django for User model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412328/how-to-load-sql-fixture-in-django-for-user-model).  This has some code on using SQL files for fixtures, where you can use a SQL expression for your date requirements (e.g. GETDATE()+1 or similar in your SQL dialect).