# Django - Custom Sql for the User model

Tags: sql, django, django-models

Which name need the sql-file in the sql folder? When I want to load custom sql for the User Model.

[Initial SQL Data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link you provided :

The hook is simple: Django just looks for a file called sql/`modelname`.sql, in your app directory, where `modelname` is the model's name in lowercase.

So, if you had a Person model in an app called myapp, you could add arbitrary SQL to the file sql/person.sql inside your myapp directory. Here's an example of what the file might contain:

Comment: I know but I currently try to load custom sql for the django auth User model

Comment: Ah, I see - sorry. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412328/how-to-load-sql-fixture-in-django-for-user-model)